# R (rmarkdown) slide presentation pdf adapt table

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

thanks for you help in advance.

I'm using Rmarkdown and trying to adapt a big table to a page, but I can't figure out a solution to my problem. 
This is my code: 
[image: Beamer code]

...and this is how the pdf comes out: 
[image: Slide: table]

Can someone help me? 
Thanks a lot.

Matteo.

Answer (score -1):

Use a little raw latex to modify the tables width:

````
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
```{r, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(cbind(iris, iris), format = 'latex')
```
}
````

Here we set the width to be equal to the textwidth of the document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin, I do really appreciate your help!
I'm really close to what I would like to do now (your solution it's very clear), but the pdf comes out like this now: http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ldwnia&s=9#.WRyRemjyg2w (in RED the code I used) ... Can you help me "hiding" the code? in the pdf? AND can I use this code also for functions outcomes?(like "summary")

sorry but everything is new for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: For starters set `echo=F`